# How to resolve incorrect fortran read from data text file?

Tags: file-io, fortran

I have a text file with two numbers on the same line

```
108  6.7522
```

I have a fortran subroutine READCN that stores the numbers 108  6.7522 from the text file into the variables NN and BOX

```
    SUBROUTINE READCN ( CNFILE, BOX )
    CHARACTER   CNFILE*(*)
    REAL        BOX
    INTEGER     CNUNIT
    PARAMETER ( CNUNIT = 10 )
    INTEGER     NN
    OPEN ( UNIT = CNUNIT, FILE = CNFILE, STATUS = 'OLD',
 :         FORM = 'UNFORMATTED'                        )

    READ ( CNUNIT ) NN, BOX
    WRITE(*,*) NN, BOX
    CLOSE ( UNIT = CNUNIT )
    RETURN
    END
```

The output for READCN variables NN BOX is

```
   3.2997999      2.74554597E-31
```

How do I read the values correctly?

This program is taken from http://www.ccl.net/cca/software/SOURCES/FORTRAN/allen-tildesley-book/f.12

When I attempted to remove the format option in the read command this was the follow error I received

```
At line 686 of file MCNPT.f (unit = 10, file = 'LATTICE-256.txt')
Fortran runtime error: Missing format for FORMATTED data transfer
```

Comment: By "remove the format option in the read command" you mean "remove the `form='unformatted'` in the `open` statement"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving from using unformatted input to formatted input requires three actions:

- changing the input to a "text file";
- opening the file for formatted, rather than unformatted, I/O;
- providing a format for the read statements.

You've done the first two of these.  [If you didn't know, removing `form='unformatted'` means that the default of formatted I/O is used.]

All that remains is to use a format specifier in the subsequent `read`s.  This is where the compiler is complaining.

The simplest formatted read to use is *list-directed*, which is given by `fmt=*` specifier in the `read`.  This should be sufficient for your case, but you should ensure you are happy with its limitations.

To be precise: replace

```
      OPEN ( UNIT = CNUNIT, FILE = CNFILE, STATUS = 'OLD',
     :         FORM = 'UNFORMATTED'                        )
      READ ( CNUNIT ) NN, BOX
```

with

```
      OPEN ( UNIT = CNUNIT, FILE = CNFILE, STATUS = 'OLD')
      READ ( CNUNIT, * ) NN, BOX
```

Comment: How can I use this to resolve the issue with not reading the numbers correctly?

Comment: At line 687 of file MCNPT.f (unit = 10, file = 'LATTICE-256.txt')
Fortran runtime error: Format present for UNFORMATTED data transfer

Comment: Sorry, two changes required to the code in the question.  I was assuming the edit implied you had already applied the one to the `open`.

Comment: no worries i think it worked, I have a another error to debug unrelated to this, but thanks for answering so quickly