# Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 0 in list input?

Tags: file-io, fortran

How do I fix the Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 0 in list input?

Below is the Fortran program which generates a runtime error.

```
    CHARACTER   CNFILE*(*)
    REAL        BOX
    INTEGER     CNUNIT
    PARAMETER ( CNUNIT = 10 )
    INTEGER     NN
    OPEN ( UNIT = CNUNIT, FILE = CNFILE, STATUS = 'OLD' )
    READ ( CNUNIT,* ) NN, BOX
```

The error message received from gdb is :

```
At line 688 of file MCNPT.f (unit = 10, file = 'LATTICE-256.txt')
Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 0 in list input
[Inferior 1 (process 3052) exited with code 02]
(gdb)
```

I am not sure what options must be specified for READ() to read to numbers from the text file. Does it matter if the two numbers on the same line are specified as either an integer or a real in the text file?

Below is the gdb execution of the program using a break point at the open call

```
Breakpoint 1, readcn (
    cnfile=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffffffdff0>, 
    box=-3.37898272e+33, _cnfile=30) at MCNPT.f:686
```

Comment: Now you've added list-directed formatted input (`read(CNUNIT,*)`) the error message in the question doesn't make much sense.  But the error in the question title makes much more.  Could you clarify which is appropriate?

Comment: @francescalus I edited the post in attempt to provide clarity. Let me know if this is not clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if you try to read something like `-1.5` into an integer variable you could get an error message very much like that given here.  Line 688 really is this `read` statement?  Also, try adding `position='rewind'` to the `open` if you do mean to read the first line from the file.

Comment: Also, the edits have perhaps invalidated the answer given already, so it may possibly be good to roll those back and start a new question.  [But I'm no expert on SO protocols.]

Answer (score 3):

Since you did not specify `form="unformatted"` on the open statement, the unit / file is opened for formatted IO.  This is appropriate for a human-readable text file.  ("unformatted" would be used for a non-human readable file in computer-native format, sometimes called "binary".)   Therefore you should provide a format on the read, or use list-directed read, i.e., `read(unit, *)`.   To advise on a particular format we would have to know the layout of the numbers in the file.  A possible read with format is: `read (CNUINT, '(I4, 2X, F6.2)' ) NN, BOX`

P.S.  I'm answering the question in your question and not the title, which seems unrelated.

EDIT: now that you are show the text data file, a list-directed read looks easier.  That is because the data doesn't line up in columns.   It seems that the file has two integers on the first line, then three real numbers on each of the following lines.   Most likely you need a different read for the first line.   Is the code sample that you are showing us trying to read the first line, or one of the later lines?   If the first line, it would seem plausible to read into two integer variables. If a later line, into two or three real variables.  Two if you wish to skip the third data item on the line.

EDIT 2: the question has been substantially altered several times, which is very confusing.  The first line of the text file that was shown in one version of the question contained integers, with later lines having reals.  Since the listed-directed read is reading into an integer and a floating variable, it will have problems if you attempt to use it on the later lines that have two real values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I posted the text file. Am I supposed to specify the format of each line, line by line in the open function?

Comment: @linuxfreebird Changing this code to use list-directed input is in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23713153/3157076) to your previous question.

Comment: @francescalus I added the (,*) to my post. I think I am receive the same problem using what I think is the suggested solution, but still receiving errors.

Comment: @linuxfreebird I'm getting confused - but I'll comment on the question instead of this answer.